# inspect next element in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

You can leave an element alone in a list comprehension according to a condition like this:

```
>>> mylist = [6,7,3,9,2,7,4]
>>> [x-1 if x!=7 else x for x in mylist]
[5, 7, 2, 8, 1, 7, 3]
```

What I need however is that the element is left alone if the element after it is 7.

```
[x-1 if next_element!=7 else x for x in mylist]
```

Desired output is:

```
[6,6,2,8,2,6,3]
```

I thought this might have been possible with enumerate and the index but can't work it out. Any ideas?

Comment: `[x if y==7 else x-1 for x, y in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])]` or some *lazy* eqivalent

Comment: @Chris_Rands, No, that does not add last element in list.

Comment: ..but was almost it

Comment: @Austin yes, sometimes I wish zip_longest was the default behaviour

Comment: @Chris_Rands, `zip_longest` is ofcourse one way. Wonder, why no one has come up with it so far.

Comment: @Austin IMO it's the best way to solve this problem actually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enumerate` and `index` is one way, but you can do it with `zip`:

```
mylist = [6,7,3,9,2,7,4]
[x[0]-(x[1]!=7) for x in zip(mylist, mylist[1:] + [0])]

# [6, 6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
mylist = [6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 7, 4]

result = [current - 1 if ne != 7 else current for current, ne in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])] + [mylist[-1] - 1]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[6, 6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not  a big fan of using one-liners when it becomes too complicated to read, but that works and the list is parsed only once:

```
mylist = [6,7,3,9,2,7,4]
L = len(mylist)
a = [x-1 if (i+1<N and mylist[i+1]!=7 or i==N-1) else x for i, x in enumerate(mylist)]
```

If you work with big lists and want to improve performance, you can do `L = len(mylist)` outside of the list comprehension and replace it in the condition.

Comment: is almost it except for last element, but only one which tried to use `enumerate`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question directly, but I find list comprehension should used in simple cases and avoid when the statement becomes overly complicated. See Googles [styleguide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#27-comprehensions--generator-expressions) for more detail.

I find the following much more readable.

```
mylist = [6,7,3,9,2,7,4]
newlist = []
length = len(mylist)
for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
  if index + 1 < length and mylist[index + 1] == 7:
    newlist.append(item)
  else:
    newlist.append(item - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of other things going on in the code where I am using/adapting this and did not feel that that one deserved more than one line. Did not want to spread the thought out over a "paragraph"..

Comment: I think the fix for what you are mentioning is to maybe turn this readable code into a function? I would favor self-describing function over code that is condensed to the point it is not maintainable/readable. **My opinion**